# Creating a table with all possible variations of observations

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I have an Excel spreadsheet of data with outputs and features to predict this output. For example a row of a certain output will look similar to this:

```
 Y     X1     X2     X3     X4     X5
 A     Y      N      Y
```

The variables X1, X2, and X3 are important and have to be Y, N, Y respectively to get the correct Y output. However, X4 and X5 can be anything. X4 can be Y, N, or NA; X5 can be any number 1-10. I want to use Python to make all variations of this output. So I want something like this:

```
Y     X1     X2     X3    X4     X5
A     Y      N      Y     Y      1
A     Y      N      Y     Y      2
A     Y      N      Y     Y      3
.
.
A     Y      N      Y     N      1
.
.
etc.
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Itertools has many built-in combination and permutation operations https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy to do if you use the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) combinatoric generator in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module.

What you haven't said is exactly what form you want the output to be in, so I've assumed (csv file-like) tab-delimited strings. Each raw row produced in the `for` loop is a tuple of values like `('Y', 'N', 'Y', 'NA', 7)` but you can readily change this as necessary (one example is shown far below).

```
from itertools import product

possible_observations = [
    ['Y'],             # X1
    ['N'],             # X2
    ['Y'],             # X3
    ['Y', 'N', 'NA'],  # X4
    range(1, 11)       # X5
]

print('\t'.join(('X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5')))  # column headers
for row in product(*possible_observations):
    print('\t'.join(map(str, row)))
```

Output (with `»` representing a tab character):

```
X1»   X2»   X3»   X4»   X5
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    1
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    2
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    3
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    4
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    5
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    6
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    7
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    8
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    9
Y»    N»    Y»    Y»    10
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    1
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    2
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    3
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    4
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    5
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    6
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    7
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    8
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    9
Y»    N»    Y»    N»    10
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   1
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   2
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   3
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   4
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   5
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   6
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   7
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   8
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   9
Y»    N»    Y»    NA»   10
```

If you instead wanted to save all the variations in a list, that could be done like this:

```
possible_combinations = list(product(*possible_observations))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for what I was trying to do. However, I have another question. If I wanted to save this into an Excel file or csv file, how would I save these rows to do that? I tried to make it into a list rather than tab-delimited strings and assign the list a name but when I do that I only get a list of the last row of variations.

Comment: You could make them into a list with `combos = [row for row in product(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5)]`. To create a csv file, just `file.write()` each tab-delimited string as a line of a file opened for writing by adding a newline (`'\n'`) character to the end of each. If you would prefer comma-delimited just change the  `'\t'.join` to `','.join`.

Comment: P.S. You can, of course, also use a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) object to create a csv file. However, creating an Excel file would require using one of the many third-party modules available.

Comment: I actually just figured something out that seems to have worked for me. I made it into a list and used data.append(list()) then created a data frame to save it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `product` function of the `itertools` module.
Here is a sample code:

```
  from itertools import product

  X4 = ['Y', 'N', 'NA']
  X5 = list(range(1,11))
  Ct = ['A', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']

  for elt in  product(X4, map(str, X5) ) :
     print( '\t'.join( Ct[:] + list(elt)  )  )
```

Comment: The whole point of `itertools.product` is so you don't have to create a potentially very large list like `M` when you can instead just iterate through the values it yields.

Comment: Thank you @martineau  for this comment, I edited the answer according to what you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
def all_variations():
    rows = []
    for letter in ['Y', 'N', 'NA']:
        for number in range(1,11):
            row = ['A', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', letter, number]
            rows.append(row)
    return rows
```

and if you want your column names you can use pandas and make a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = all_variations()
cols = ['Y'] + ['X{number}'.format(number=num) for num in range(1,6)]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

print df
```